# How to run a seperate python program within a python program?

Tags: python, cmd, automation, exec

I am trying to implement a program that is executing another program over and over until the second program returns a proper output.

But the first program must not be halted after an error that occurred in the second program. I tried something like this, but the exec() function is not what I am looking for.

```
input_file = 'report.txt'
source_code = 'insert_prices.py'
correct_flag = 26
current_flag = 0

while(1):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
        current_flag = int(file. readline().split(None, 1)[0])
    if(current_flag == correct_flag):
        break
    else:
        exec(open(source_code, encoding='utf-8').read())
```

Comment: If you need to execute program, you don't need to read it. Please read about subprocess library. It is lib that can run terminal commands.

Comment: you can use os.system('python yourscript.py'), or use subprocess module or even multiprocessing module if you need your code to run in paralell